# Python IOError: [Errno 2] from recursive directory call

Tags: python, file-io, io, directory, subdirectory

The code below is part of a program I am writing that runs a method on every .py, .sh. or .pl file in a directory and its folders.

```
for root, subs, files in os.walk("."):
    for a in files:
        if a.endswith('.py') or a.endswith('.sh') or a.endswith('.pl'):
            scriptFile = open(a, 'r')
            writer(writeFile, scriptFile)
            scriptFile.close()
        else:
            continue
```

When writing the program, it worked in the directory tree I wrote it in, but when I moved it to another folder to try it there I get this error message:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "versionTEST.py", line 75, in <module>
scriptFile = open(a, 'r')
IOError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'enabledLogSources.sh'
```

I know something weird is going on because the file is most definitely there...

Comment: Was your test directory multiple levels deep? enabledLogSources.sh down a layer from the directory you're running this script in?

Comment: `open(os.path.join("{}/{}".format(root,a)),"r")`

Comment: where is `writeFile` coming from?

Comment: @PadraicCunningham thanks I'll try it and it is higher up in the program, that's the file I create to write to.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll need to prepend the root directory to your filename

```
scriptFile = open(root + '/' + a, 'r')
```

Answer (score 1):

files contains only the file names, not the entire path. The path to the file can be obtained by joining the file name and the root:

```
scriptFile = open(os.path.join(root, a), "r")
```

You might want to have a look at
https://docs.python.org/2/library/os.html#os.walk